# CAS azure saml2 Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, cas

I have configured CAS to use a delegated saml2 authentication with Azure, it works but after a day i get this error message when i try to log in.

```
Unauthorized Access
Either the authentication request was rejected/cancelled, or the authentication provider denied access due to permissions, etc. Review logs to find the root cause of the issue.
```

Looking at the logs for CAS i see this error message `Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future` i checked [Azures saml2 token lifetime documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) and it says token should have max life of 1 day
but as you can see in this log this seems to be longer then 1 day.

```
2021-11-23 11:51:31,673 WARN 2021-11-23 11:58:51,835 WARN [org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2AuthnResponseValidator] - <interval=86400,before=2021-11-23T12:03:51.835173Z,after=2021-11-22T11:53:51.835173Z,issueInstant=2021-11-16T12:33:14.319Z>
2021-11-23 11:51:31,675 ERROR [org.pac4j.saml.sso.impl.SAML2AuthnResponseValidator] - <Current assertion validation failed, continue with the next one>
org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLAuthnInstantException: Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future
```

Right now i have set `cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].maximumAuthenticationLifetime=86400` (1day) but i then i keep getting this error. how can i either make azure reissue a new token or get the exakt life time of the token on azure so i don't get this error message again.

Answer (score 0):

you issue  issueInstant=2021-11-16T12:33:14.319Z

your after=2021-11-22T11:53:51.835173Z

you are telling it you issued the request at a certain date but it has to be after the after date

Comment: Yes the After is controlled by the `maximumAuthenticationLifetime` but my question is how do i find out the correct value for it (since Azures documentation says 1 day but that's not correct), or make Azure renew its issue date.